# changing password - Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring MVC 3.0 application with spring security implemented. I am creating a small pop-up to change the password of the current loging in user. All is well until I post the form to the following action.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "principalchangepassword" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String principalchangepassword(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
    Principal principal = (Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    StandardStringDigester digester = new StandardStringDigester();
    digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");   // optionally set the algorithm
    digester.setStringOutputType("hexadecimal");
    digester.setSaltSizeBytes(0);
    digester.setIterations(1);
    String digest = digester.digest(httpServletRequest.getParameter("password1")); 
    principal.setPassword(digest.toLowerCase());
    principal.merge();
    return "Password Updated successfully";
}
```

When I do an ajax call to update the password of the current principal, I get the following exception message.

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance – save the transient instance before flushing
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: could you describe the method does principal.merge?

Comment: Merge is used for already existing entities, that is, already stored in the database. If it a totally new principal, i would have said principal.persist();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so insted of using the principal I got from the statement

```
(Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

I needed to first use the ID to explicitly liad the pricipal from the database, make my changes and then merge. Here is the final action which is working perfectly.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "principalchangepassword" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String principalchangepassword(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
    Principal principal = (Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    Principal me = Principal.findPrincipal(principal.getId());
    me.setPassword(httpServletRequest.getParameter("password1"));
    StandardStringDigester digester = new StandardStringDigester();
    digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");   // optionally set the algorithm
    digester.setStringOutputType("hexadecimal");
    digester.setSaltSizeBytes(0);
    digester.setIterations(1);
    String digest = digester.digest(me.getPassword());
    me.setPassword(digest.toLowerCase());
    me.merge();
    return "Password Updated successfully";
}
```

Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: `java.security.Principal` has no `getId()` method. `me.setPassword()` is called twice which makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

I am using spring security using BCryptPasswordEncoder. Now for change password i do is to compare Existing Password provided by user with DB value.

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String existingPassword = ... // Password entered by user
String dbPassword       = ... // Load hashed DB password

if (passwordEncoder.matches(existingPassword, dbPassword)) {
    // Encode new password and store it
} else {
    // Report error 
}
```

Comment: `No signature of method: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.encoding.BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

Comment: this is actually correct answer. Its working flawless in spring boot 1.5.15.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I was looking for a way to create a new user and set an encoded password.
Binaryrespawn's answer is already quite good, I just want to add a second view to this question.

So in order to change a password or create a new user it is not really necessary to interact with Spring. Except than to ensure you are authenticated (and for creating a new user that you have the permissions).

The most importent part is, that the PasswordEncoder matches the one that is configured in spring and that the AuthenticationProvider will use to compare the stored password with the one that the user entered.

The steps to update the password are basically:

1. Load the existing user from the database (by `id` or `username`).
2. Get the PasswordEncoder that spring uses to authenticate.
3. Store the user.

The steps to create a new user are basically:

1. Retrieve a user object from the frontend.
2. Get the PasswordEncoder that Spring uses to authenticate
3. Replace the password that the user send with the encoded version and put it back into the user object.
4. Store the user.

Here is an example that defines a REST endpoint to create a new user:

```
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

@POST
@Path("user/create")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public User createUser(User user) {
    if(user.getPassword() == null || user.getPassword().equals("")) {
        //throw exception...
    }
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userService.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

Comment: if you were looking for a way to create user, change password, etc - this might help: i wrote a project that implements all these flows. have a look here... let me know if it is not clear etc https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample/tree/master/authentication-flows