# How to refresh the Security Context after the password change in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a method that changes the user's password in database, but that's the half of the battle. I also need to renew the session context in which the user data is situated.

For example:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
/* ...password changing steps...*/ 
user.setPassword(newPassword); //set the new password in the database
/* ...something I need to do to insert the new password into the Security Context... */
```

So what do I need to write in code to refresh the session information after the password change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing password - Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525308/changing-password-spring-security)

Comment: Not exactly. I don't know why but the Principal class in my project doesn't contain the methods listed there